# When is it useful to refresh a ParseInstallation?

Tags: parse-platform

Without going on details, is there a condition where is useful to call `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refresh()`?

I'm thinking about a situation where a user has more than one device and he use them "alternated", with the same login credentials. Should this call keep its subscription consistent or is it only a source of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call refresh if you think the data has changed on the server side and want the updated data.

Unless you're altering Installation records in Cloud Code, or in the data browser, you probably don't need to refresh the installation.

It wouldn't really come into play with the multiple device scenario, as each device would have its own installation record.